# How does scanf work in this simple program?

Tags: c, scanf

I have some trouble working with scanf in a while loop. 
I wanted to make a program that would ask the user to write three integers and save them in an array of three positions. If the user writes something which is not an integer, the program should continue asking for an integer until (s)he enters it. But it didn't work properly.

So I tried to simplify the problem with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1=1;
    int num2=2;
    int num3=3;

    printf ("write a number\n");
    scanf("%i", &(num1));
    printf("%i\n",num1);

    printf ("write a number2\n");
    scanf("%i", &(num2));
    printf("%i\n",num2);

    printf ("write a number3\n");
    scanf("%i", &(num3));
    printf("%i\n",num3);
}
```

If the inputs are 3 integers, there's no problem. But if you write a character, for example a, for the first integer, the other 2 values are not scanned and it simply writes:
a
2
3
The last two values are the initialization values.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do?

Comment: You have to use `fgets()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But could you please explain me what is happening?

Comment: @Trouble-lling Actually, I don't exactly know. I don't use `scanf()`, exactly for its pieces of misbehavior like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanf function does not have to read after it encounters the first invalid character in the input.

The %i specifier allows a as a hexadecimal, but it MUST be preceded by 0x.

If `a` was the first character in the input, and it was supposed to match to `%i`, then scanf wouldn't have to read anything afterwards - it can stop at the first invalid character..

References:
http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-64.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.The link helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For each conversion specifier `scanf` tries to locate the appropriate data item. `scanf` reads the item, stopping when it encounters a character that can't possibly belongs to the item. If any item is not read successfully then `scanf` returns immediately without looking at the rest of the format string.
When you enter `a 5 10`, `scanf` finds `a` for the specifier `%i`. It immediately returns and stops reading other inputs `5` and `10`.

Comment: BTW, is it just me, or is this a direct quote from some man page? It's sounds very familiar to me.

Comment: @H2CO3; Mee too :). I read this in a book. But not from `man` page.

Comment: No, it's not a quote H2C03.

Comment: @Trouble-lling; Mark the 'V' icon on the left of the answer.

Comment: I've just realized it. Thank you haccks :)

Comment: @Trouble-lling apparently, it is a quote.

Comment: My question is not a quote but, of course, you can think so. I can't understand why you insist so much ¿?

Comment: @Trouble-lling It's not your question that I was referring to. It's the answer of haccks I am talking about.

Comment: @H2CO3; What is happening here. I do not understand yet. From where is this word "quote" come into exist? o.O. Did I missed something?

Comment: @haccks I remember having read the text of your answer somewhere else, I thought it was some man page. Then you confirmed that it was a quote from a book. Trouble-lling insisted that it wasn't, I then pointed out that it indeed was. He thought that I was talking about his question, so I informed him that I wasn't.

Comment: @H2CO3; I posted almost the similar answer few months ago (I do not remember the title of the question). May be you read that answer. I think that's why you thought that (may be).

Comment: @haccks not a problem, this was more about the tiny bit of misunderstanding between OP and me.

Comment: Ok, I'm very sorry H2CO3. I didn't understand you yesterday. You were talking about the answer. Now I get it. Thanks.